# Adding Equinox to Eclipse Mars

Tags: equinox, eclipse-mars

I am trying to develop some applications under OSGI platform and to do that ,i must use Eclipse (Mars version) that contain Equinox.
My question is : How to add **Equinox** to **Eclipse Mars** ?

Comment: It is already part of it.

Comment: Since Eclipse itself is an OSGi program it already includes Equinox.

Comment: but i can not find plug-in project 's type when i want to create a new project with this type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Eclipse itself is an OSGi program it already includes Equinox.

To create an OSGi project use 'File > New > Project... > Plug-in Project' (also look in 'File > New > Project... > Plug-in Development > Plug-in Project')

On the first page of the new project wizard select 'Equinox' in the 'Target Platform' section.

[image: Target Platform]

Comment: in Eclipse Mars , i can not find Plug-in Project as a type of project

Comment: This is Eclipse Mars. You may have to look in 'File > New > Project... > Plug-in Development > Plug-in Project'.

Comment: also Plug-in Development not found

Comment: In which case you don't have the plugin development code installed. Some of the Eclipse downloads don't include it. Either use 'Install New Software' to install it into your existing Eclipse or download one of the packages which includes it.

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution, i add "Eclipse plug-in" from "Install New Software"